# How to merge pyspark dataframe and drop null values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pyspark dataframe structure:

```
device | value_0|value_1|value_2|value_3|
   1     43      null    null    null
   2     null    22      null    null
   3     null    null    5       null
   4     null    null    null    89
   1     44      null    null    null
   2     null    23      null    null
   3     null    null    6       null
   4     null    null    null    90
```

My goal is to merge the columns:

```
      device|value|
       1     43      
       2     22      
       3     5 
       4     89
       1     44      
       2     23
       3     6      
       4     90
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `F.coalesce` to merge nulls:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.select('device',
    F.coalesce(
        *[F.col(col) for col in ['value_0', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']]
    ).alias('value')
)
```